# How can I match items each other without using too much if/elif statements?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way without using too much `if/elif` statements to search items when the below conditions are met.  Else, more efficient way.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import json
from form import Character_Assessment
class Dominant:
    def __init__(self):
     

           self.character1=[a,b,c]
           self.character2=[a,b,c]
           self.character3=[a,b,c]
           self.character4=[a,b,c]
           self.character5=[a,b,c]
           self.character6=[a,b,c]

    def find_match(self):
        self.y_1 = 0
        self.x_1 = 0
            

        for f in self.extrovert:
                q3 = tk.simpledialog.askstring(title="Please type 'y','dmt','ext'", prompt=f)
                if q3 == "y":
                    self.x_1 += 1
                elif q3 == "dmt":
                    self.x_1 += 1.5
                elif q3 == "ext":
                    self.x_1 += 2
        if 0 <=self.x_1 <= 16 and 2.25<=self.y_1<3:
            with open("Draft.txt", mode="a") as dr:
                dr.write(f"Specific:\n {self.character3[5]}")
        elif 0 <=self.x_1 <= 16 and 1.5<=self.y_1<2.25:
            with open("Draft.txt", mode="a") as dr:
                dr.write(f"Specific:\n {self.character3[6]}")
        elif 0 <=self.x_1 <= 16 and 0<=self.y_1<1.5:
            with open("Draft.txt", mode="a") as dr:
                dr.write(f"Specific:\n {self.character3[7]}")
                          .
                          .(20 more conditions)
                          .
```

My purpose is without writing so long lines, matching elements.

Comment: Nested ifs? one for the x boundary that repeats and one for the y boundaries?

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Put your values into a list of tuples (or lists) and use a `for` loop.

Comment: `if 0 < x < 16: if 2.25 < y < 3` ... its not really less if statements per say but its more efficient for the `elif` statements since you're not rechecking the same condition

Comment: Also, you only need to open your file for writing once. Why are you doing it in each condition?

Comment: It might be worth just doing the writing and opening files after the if statement anyway and just using the if statements to work out what value you need to format into that string

Comment: "Also, you only need to open your file for writing once. Why are you doing it in each condition?" I thought if I open a file, then I need to repeat it every time opening, reading, and adding tasks. so the code will be much longer than this.

Comment: "Put your values into a list of tuples (or lists) and use a for loop." x and y define a coordinate system. x (-16,16)/y(0-6)/(6-12)